# Optimised Postgres query for date frequency counting

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a table like

```
  CREATE TABLE events (
    id serial primary key,
    name character varying(255),
    created_at timestamp(6)
  )
```

with millions of rows at various dates.

**I want to count the number of events that are X days from Y date**. Y date is not known in advance.

So given data like

```
id    name      created_at
1     event1    2017-01-02 12:00:00
2     event1    2017-01-03 12:00:00
3     event1    2017-01-03 12:00:00
4     event1    2017-01-04 12:00:00
5     event1    2017-01-04 12:00:00
6     event1    2017-01-04 12:00:00
7     event1    2017-01-05 12:00:00
8     event1    2017-01-05 12:00:00
```

I want to get this result for the date 2017-01-01

```
d           count
1 days      1
2 days      2
3 days      3
4 days      2
```

The best query I've come up with is

```
select date_trunc('day', age(timestamp '2018-01-01', created_at)) as "d", count(*)
FROM events
GROUP BY "d"
ORDER BY "d"
```

which gives the following output from `EXPLAIN ANALYZE`

```
GroupAggregate  (cost=134702.34..157202.34 rows=1000000 width=8) (actual time=2112.554..2457.594 rows=12 loops=1)
  Group Key: (date_trunc('day'::text, age('2018-01-01 00:00:00'::timestamp without time zone, created_at)))
  ->  Sort  (cost=134702.34..137202.34 rows=1000000 width=8) (actual time=2081.727..2277.930 rows=1000000 loops=1)
        Sort Key: (date_trunc('day'::text, age('2018-01-01 00:00:00'::timestamp without time zone, created_at)))
        Sort Method: external sort  Disk: 25424kB
        ->  Seq Scan on events  (cost=0.00..21370.00 rows=1000000 width=8) (actual time=0.021..836.849 rows=1000000 loops=1)
Planning time: 0.075 ms
Execution time: 2468.842 ms
```

Is this as efficient as I can get?

How would you optimise this query?

What strategies or Postgres features can I use instead?

**Update**

If I perform the date-shifting *after* the date grouping I can almost halve the execution time:

```
SELECT AGE(TIMESTAMP '2018-01-01', "d"), "count"
FROM (SELECT date_trunc('day', created_at) AS "d", COUNT(*)
FROM events
GROUP BY "d"
ORDER BY "d") as "date_groups"
```

Here's the analyze output

```
Subquery Scan on date_groups  (cost=132202.34..164702.34 rows=1000000 width=16) (actual time=1329.102..1854.696 rows=12 loops=1)
  ->  GroupAggregate  (cost=132202.34..152202.34 rows=1000000 width=8) (actual time=1329.089..1854.635 rows=12 loops=1)
        Group Key: (date_trunc('day'::text, events.created_at))
        ->  Sort  (cost=132202.34..134702.34 rows=1000000 width=8) (actual time=1297.415..1680.793 rows=1000000 loops=1)
              Sort Key: (date_trunc('day'::text, events.created_at))
              Sort Method: external merge  Disk: 17512kB
              ->  Seq Scan on events  (cost=0.00..18870.00 rows=1000000 width=8) (actual time=0.022..606.144 rows=1000000 loops=1)
Planning time: 0.151 ms
Execution time: 1861.552 ms
```

In the test data, the events are spread over only a few days so suspect the performance gains won't be quite as dramatic with a broader range of dates

Comment: And I'd be grateful if anyone wants to suggest a better title — is there a name for what I'm trying to do?

Comment: Store a date not a timestamp, group by that date, subtract after grouping.

Comment: "Store a date not a timestamp" —
Let's assume I might also want to do this with week, hours, minutes etc

Comment: but "group by that date, subtract after grouping" is an interesting idea

Comment: thanks @zerkms. Your suggestion definitely improved the performance

Comment: "Sort Method: external merge  Disk: 17512kB". You also need to increase [work_mem](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/runtime-config-resource.html#RUNTIME-CONFIG-RESOURCE-MEMORY).

Comment: "Seq Scan on events". Probably creating an index with expression `date_trunc('day'::text, events.created_at))` should help to avoid this seqscan. Take a look [here](https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Index-only_scans).